# How to add custom style to google maps info box

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

How to add custom style to google maps info box
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is directly explained in the documentation.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple

```
 var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<div id="siteNotice">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<h1 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">Uluru</h1>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<p><b>Uluru</b>, also referred to as <b>Ayers Rock</b>, is a large ' +
        'sandstone rock formation in the southern part of the '+
        'Northern Territory, central Australia. It lies 335&#160;km (208&#160;mi) '+
        'south west of the nearest large town, Alice Springs; 450&#160;km '+
        '(280&#160;mi) by road. Kata Tjuta and Uluru are the two major '+
        'features of the Uluru - Kata Tjuta National Park. Uluru is '+
        'sacred to the Pitjantjatjara and Yankunytjatjara, the '+
        'Aboriginal people of the area. It has many springs, waterholes, '+
        'rock caves and ancient paintings. Uluru is listed as a World '+
        'Heritage Site.</p>'+
        '<p>Attribution: Uluru, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru&oldid=297882194">'+
        'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Uluru</a> '+
        '(last visited June 22, 2009).</p>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });
```